# Browser gets stuck when Running Cypress Command

Tags: typescript, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm facing issues. I have been using Cypress for a while now and it seems like there has been some sort of dependencies issues.
The major problem I'm facing is that Whenever I'm trying to connect to any of the browsers from the Cypress UI. it just stuck on the loading and never goes forward. It is for all 4 browsers supported by Cypress. I guess it's some sort of framing issue and it doesn't connect to Cypress.

Don't know about it,

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your webpack version?
if you are using webpack version 5, in this case, it is a known issue, logged here and PR is open for this: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/pull/15611

A Temporary solution is to downgrade your webpack version to 4, it'll solve your problem for now.